# Get valid commands for enterprises.devices.executeCommand

Tags: google-api, nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

I am testing [Google Nest API](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/use-the-api) with my Nest devices (Nest Doorbell, Nest Camera)

And I am able to call following endpoints successfully with an access token issued from OAuth2 authorization process:

- [enterprises.devices.list](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list)
- [enterprises.devices.get](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get)

However, as I proceeded to testing [enterprises.devices.executeCommand](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/executeCommand), I cannot provide a valid `command` value in the request body, and received error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Command sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateRtspStream not supported.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

According to [Request Body Doc](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/executeCommand#request-body),

> The command name to execute, represented by the fully qualified protobuf message name.

It confuses me as I have no idea how to get such "fully qualified protobuf message name".

I assume that available `command` values should be a finite list, but not sure why there's no clear documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For specific API that you would like to call, you can refer to the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/camera-live-stream#generatertspstream). What you are looking at is the generic template for API calls.